# How to run code after phone calling in Swift

Tags: ios, swift3

I make call on button click. My code:

```
if let phoneCallURL:NSURL = NSURL(string: "tel://\(phoneNumber)") {
    let application:UIApplication = UIApplication.shared
    if (application.canOpenURL(phoneCallURL as URL)) {
        application.openURL(phoneCallURL as URL);
    }
    else {
        let alertController = UIAlertController(title: NSLocalizedString("CALL_C_TITLE", comment: "Call disallowed"), message: NSLocalizedString("CALL_C_DESC", comment: "This device cannot call"), preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet)
        alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("OK", comment: "OK"), style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))                
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)            
    }
}
```

This code work fine, but i want to run some code after user end call. How I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the call is ended and your application regains focus, it will receive the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActive` ([docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsnotification.name/1622953-uiapplicationdidbecomeactive)) notification. You can register your ViewController as an observer for this and respond accordingly.

Keep in mind that you will receive this notification for other event sequences too (returning from background, dismissing notifications, etc.), so you may want to set a flag when starting the call and check for that flag in the notification handler if you only want to run code after having made the call.

Comment: Ok. I do this like that: If i run calling function i set flag and when app "Become Active" i check flag. If it's true I re-run player (internet stream). Everything works well. Thanks for your help!